# ggplot labels in Rshiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Trying to do a simple thing and coming up against unexpected trouble. I am putting together an RShiny app and would like to label the points in my ggplot graph.

My code is below. I do not understand why I cannot pass in the variable flowers to get the point labels in the chart. For comparison's sake, the commented lines work completely fine when I remove all attempts at point labels (which suggests it's not a problem with variable passthroughs from other functions, etc.)

In addition, directly putting in rownames() into the aes also does not work.

Thanks for your help.

```
output$graph=renderPlot({
pairs2=pctchg()
pairs3=as.data.frame(pairs2)

rownames(pairs3)=input$vector[]
flowers=rownames(pairs3)

#basegraph=ggplot(pairs3,aes(x,y))
basegraph=ggplot(pairs3,aes(x,y,label=flowers))

globalvars=basegraph + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = 'lm') + geom_text(aes(label=flowers)) 

#globalvars=ggplot(pairs3,aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = 'lm')

print(globalvars) })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `flowers` a column of the `data.frame` you're plotting from, instead of a separate object.

`pairs3$flowers <- input$vector`

Then try your plotting code.

Comment: Thank you! So helpful. What is the intuition behind that? Does it all have to be contained within one dataframe?

Comment: As I understand, `aes` is intended to map to column names in the data.frame. If you want to use a constant or an object external to the data.frame, you need to pass it without `aes`: `ggplot(pairs3, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + geom_text(label=flowers)`. Still, I think it's safest to have everything you want to plot in a data.frame, if possible.

Comment: Okay I see. Appreciate the help, once more.